# Unable to update JSF view after commandScript

Tags: jsf, cdi

I'd need using JSF 2.3 commandScript to invoke CDI Beans from a javascript function. Unfortunately, I'm not able to render on the screen the updated CDI bean field.
In short this is my JSF page:

```
<body>           

  <h:form id="formpanel">
       <h:commandScript  execute="@form" name="submitForm" action="#{translatorBean.translate()}" render=":output"   /> 
       <h:inputText value="#{translatorBean.input}" />
       <h:button value="submit" onclick="submitForm()" />

  </h:form>
Translated:
 <h:outputText id="output" value="#{translatorBean.translated}" />
 </body>
```

I'd expect, when I hit the "submit" button that the javascript submitForm calls the CDI "translatorBean.translate()" and update the outputText with the value of "translatorBean.translated"

The CDI Bean is pretty simple, holding fields and the action method:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TranslatorBean implements Serializable {

    private String input;
    private String translated;

    // getter setter fields  
    public void translate() {

    translated = Utils.translate(input);

    }
. . . . .
}
```

In the end, the translate method gets called but the page is simply reloaded with no updates on the "translated" output.
I'm probably doing some mistakes in the JSF pages, altough I cannot figure out what. 
I'm running it on WildFly 12 using the ee8 profile. 
Thanks

Comment: Possibly you have to add a `return false` to not do a real submit.  `onclick="submitForm(); return false"`

Comment: wow, that did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: or use an `h:commandButton` with an onclick AND `type="button"` intead of an `h:button`. The 'return false' is not needed then iirc